# is there a way to declare a temp var in an if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following:

```
if line.strip().startswith("#") or line.strip().startswith('"""'):
```

I don't really want to declare a variable before to hold `line.strip()` nor repeat it twice in the `if` is there a way to hold it inside of the `if` something like:

```
if <something> _.startswith("#") or _.startswith('"""'):
```

Comment: use walrus operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! The Walrus operator!

```py
if (x := line.strip()).startswith("#") or x.startswith('"""'):
```